# Qt Virtual Keyboard hides text field

Tags: c++, qt, virtual-keyboard

I'm using Qt 5.7 for embedded UI development with Qt Creator for UI development.

When I include qtvirtualkeyboard into my UI project by setting the QT_IM_MODULE environment variable to include qtvirtualkeyboard by adding the line `qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard")` in the `main.cpp` file and adding `CONFIG += disable-desktop` in the `.pro` file

The `virtualkeyboard` that pops up when I click on any text edit fields, the keyboard is covering my TextField that I want to edit and I cannot see what I'm typing in.

I have my UI written in C++. When I click on the text field to enter the text I want to focus it and makes it comes above the keyboard. or any better ideas?

Any help is appreciated.